# GetStringUTFChars function parameter

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm developing Android app using jni.
And I used GetStringUTFChars function as follows

```
jboolean iscopy;
const char* trainfile = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, &iscopy);
```

But I saw another example like this

```
const char *inCStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, inJNIStr, NULL);
```

Both works well. But I cannot find any documentation about the former grammer even that is more concise.

Where Can I find the documentation, and Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Did you consider consulting the JNI Specification? It's all in there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first example is C++ syntax and will work only in C++ programs. The second is for C programs.

The reason the two are different is that in C++ JNIEnv is a class and the functions are member functions of the env object, while in C JNIEnv is a pointer to a struct. Since what you receive as a parameter is a pointer to JNIEnv, in C you have to dereference it to access the struct members, that's why you must use `*env` in place of `env`.

This should be covered in any text on how to use JNI, but you can also find it by reading the code in the header file.